# Eclipse, Run->Open File, The file `http://localhost......php` could not be found

Tags: php, eclipse

Suddenly Eclipse cannot find any of my files. I've deleted (removed) my projects and re-added them, but the issue persists. I'm sure it's something simple, and I'd certainly appreciate any feedback.